# Sveltekit fade out element after X seconds

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

How can I fade out element after X seconds? I don't event know where to start. Couldn't find any example with **setInterval**.

```
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
    let visible = false;
</script>

<button on:click={()=> visible=true }>
    Button  
</button>

{#if visible}
    <p in:fade>
        Hello World
    </p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to **ShadowMobX** from discord channel Sveltekit

```
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
    let visible = false;
</script>

<button on:click={() => {
    visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => visible = false, 500);
}}>
    Button
</button>

{#if visible}
    <p transition:fade>
        Hello World
    </p>
{/if}
```

live example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/d4aff66f2e3149c3947869df11127a57?version=3.56.0